# Finding the possible values of sin and tan given cosx = 3/5

Tags: trigonometry

Find the possible values of $\sin\theta$ and $\tan\theta$, given that $\cos\theta = 3/5$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$.

Here is my working out:

Using a right hand triangle: 
$$\cos\theta =a/c$$
$$\cos\theta =3/5$$

$$a^2 = b^2 + c^2$$

$$5^2= 3^2+ b^2$$

Therefore $b=+ 4$ or $- 4$.

Compute the values of $b$ and $c$ to find $\sin\theta$

$$\sin\theta = b/ c = 4/5$$

$$\tan\theta = \sin/\cos = (3/5)  / (4/5)$$
$$\tan\theta = 4/5.$$

Is this right?
Or is it better to do this is in a graph?

Comment: Actually the result is $\frac 4 3$. Also you can use directly $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$

Comment: For writing future questions, note that you should put entire equations between `$` signs rather than putting `$`s around every single symbol you want to format. Line endings in your input do not cause new lines to occur in the output, but `$$...$$` _does_ put the math on line(s) by itself. Don't use spacing to indicate grouping of operands, use parentheses.

Comment: Also for working problems in general, if you're going to use symbols (and often you should), be consistent. You wrote $\cos \theta = a/c$ but a few lines later you substitute $5$ for $a$ and $3$ for $c$ in a different equation, which would have meant $\cos \theta = 5/3$, obviously not what you intended to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right. I think you should specify what's wrong with $b=-4$ though. The question says that $\theta$ has to be between 0 and $\pi/2$. That's the problem. Also just to clarify, it should be sin $\theta$ and tan $\theta$, not just sin and tan. The way I see it is that it's like writing the square root sign without anything underneath. Actually yes, tan$\theta$ should be 4/3.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that.